# BFS On a Bipartite graph; Shortest Path between two points

Tags: c++, vector, graph, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

Here's an assumption that I'm making, before I get started, tell me if I am wrong:

- Representing a bipartite graph (shown below): I can do this with a nxm matrix where n is one side and m is the other and there's a 1 at the index if they are connected, correct?

[image]

Anyways, I'm trying to represent an "erdos" number kind of thing, or a "kevin bacon number" kind of thing, where one side is movies and the other side is actors. So far I have 2 vectors that hold each movie and actor and my adjacency  matrix is a matrix of nodes (each nodes contains a movie name, actor name, and adjacency boolean/number), which are 1 if the actor is in that movie and 0 otherwise:

[image]

I want to figure out how many degrees of separation there are between two actors (i.e. if actor A was in movie 1, actor B was in movie 1 and 2, and actor C was in movie 2, the degrees between A and C is 2; 0 if the same actor).

My questions are, am I doing it right so far? How do I continue? I know BFS uses a queue but I can't seem to get it right, or even start on the right path. What do I compare? It's like I know what to do but I can't seem to think of it at all. I have two functions which give me the index of the requested actor in the actors vector (and one for the movie), which give me the row and column indices of the adjacency matrix vector, in order to see the node at that index.